# Building a ScrumBoard to learn Django

Tags: python, django, web-services

I am currently learning Django via Youtube, Udemy, and PluralSight so that I can make programs for our non-profit foundation. I'm running into a slew of issues from the stuff I started with from PluralSight.

The current problem is I keep getting an error:

```
path(r'^scrumboard/', include('scrumboard.urls')),
NameError: name 'include' is not defined
```

Directory:

```
/djangular (the project folder)
/djangular/djangular (where my scrumboard directory/manage.py sits)
/djangular/djangular/djangular (where urls.py, the file throwing the error sits)
```

The code:

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path

urlpatterns = [
    path(r'^admin/', admin.sites.urls),
    path(r'^scrumboard/', include('scrumboard.urls')),
]
```

So far I have followed the directions to the t, and ran into countless problems, I am assuming this is another one. It initially wanted me to use the word "url" instead of path, which caused failures immediately.

Is this another one of those situations, and are there other resources I can use to learn django? This one isnt panning out for me so well, but I really do want to be able to write my own code, and I love the language and the features. Im just not a professional coder. I dont expect my work to be pretty, but I do want to get the job done.

I would really appreciate any assistance.

Comment: This was also supposed to be tagged for Django and Python, can someone please move it to the appropriate directory?

Comment: There is an "edit" link below the tag, you can add multiple tags by typing into the "tags" text-area

Answer (score 0):

You need to import `include` in your code, like so:

```
from django.conf.urls import include
```

Also (as you said), you'd usually use `url` instead of `path`, like this:

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.conf.urls import url, include

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^admin/', admin.sites.urls),
    url(r'^scrumboard/', include('scrumboard.urls')),
]
```

Comment: HAZAAAAH! It worked! ..... And now I see how developers feel. Fixed the issue, and it immediately spit out 4 more errors XD

Thank you so much for your help!

Comment: So when I try to use url instead of path, I get another error, NameError: name 'url' is not defined. 

I take it like the other one, i need to import something. 

My guess is....

from django.urls import url

Is that right?

Comment: @Fallenour I've written the import in the answer (both `url` and `include` in the same line), check it ;)

Comment: I just saw that, I made the changes, and it looks a lot cleaner this way, I really like it.

Also, is there a way I can track all the imports that I use across my program(s). Im not a professional developer, but im sure at some point we will have them, and Id like to make good notes so that they can more easily take over the projects.

Plus it helps me keep from being a repeat offender, as Im sure ill copy/pasta some of this code at some point in the near future.

Additionally, Im having simliar issues in the scrumboard directory, list is not defined this time. Missing an import?